# Socket connection to VM

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu

I'm doing a socket connection. Therefor I have a main win machine which is running a Ubuntu VM. If I start my socket-server class on main machine, I can run the client socket class on ubuntu. Everything is fine.

My machine does a dyndns, and port forwarding is enabled for the socket port in my router.
By dyndns I can connect from VM to main.

But the other way around does not work! How can I connect through dyndns from my main machine?

Comment: I can't make much sense out of this. Please clarify your question. It seems to me all you have to is move your code into the VM and adjust the hostnames or addresses, which doesn't exactly merit an SO question on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to make a port forwarding special within my vitualmachine program (virtualbox). Obvious it is no sufficient for a VM to having port forwarding enabled just in the router, which I had.